# Maildir and mail attachments

Tags: email, attachment, maildir

If the mail receive with attachments and mail storage in the server - Maildir. How attachment set in Maildir format?

For example: I user maildir for incoming message in my server. I got 1 message with attachment, I set this message in /user/new dir, where must i set attachment for this message?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Is your question about how the attachment is encoded in the mail stored in the Maildir directory ? If yes, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME (and also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Mail body + attachment(s) are in the same file.